# C# Console Application: How do I open a textfile maximized?

Tags: c#, text, console

**Hello!** (I'm new to StackOverflow)

I have a question concerning **C# Console**.

I want to open a .txt File which is in the same directory. 
This is my Code (the name of the text file is README.txt):

```
string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\README.txt";
string[] FileContents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path);                       
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);
```

The code works fine, but I want the text file to be opened maximized. How do I make this?

Comment: I'm guessing that the file is opening in notepad, and you want to have notepad be maximized when it opens? You don't need to read the file contents when you start the path...

Comment: No "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(path);" opens the Textfile. But only in a normal seized window.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It opens the default editor for the text file, which I'm assuming is notepad.

Comment: thats what i meant, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By specifying the [ProcessStartInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) parameters:

```
string notepadPath = Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\notepad.exe";

var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(notepadPath)
{
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Maximized,
    Arguments = "README.txt" 
};

Process.Start(startInfo);
```

Comment: "wherever notepad.exe is", but which path do I have to take? The program should not only run on my computer.

Comment: Usually notepad.exe can be run without specifying the path because it is in PATH environment variable. So just `var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");` will work

Comment: Notepad is in the system directory, so the updated code should work